# Proof that a set is closed

Tags: real-analysis

In preperation for my end of semester exams, I came across the following question:

Let {$Ω_α : α ∈ I $} be an arbitrary family of closed sets $Ω_α ⊆ ℝ^d$ with an index set
I.

Prove that $\underset{α∈I}∩ Ω_α$ is a closed set.

Prove that when $d=2$, $\underset{α∈I}∪  Ω_α$ isn't necessarily closed.

I know that the definition for a closed set is one whos complement is an open set, and that it contains all of its limit points.

However, for the 9 marks this question was apparently worth, that won't suffice.

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't depend on the dimension that $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}\Omega_\alpha$ isn't necessarily closed.

It depends on the tools which you are allowed to use how to prove the statement.

Do you have:

1) $$\mathbb R^d\setminus\left(\bigcap_{\alpha \in I}\Omega_\alpha\right)=\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}\left(\mathbb R^d\setminus\Omega_\alpha\right)$$

2) If $\{\mathcal O_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in J}$ is a family of open sets for an arbitrary index set $J$, then $\bigcup_{\alpha\in J} \mathcal O_\alpha$ is open.

From 1) and 2) you can deduce the claim. If 1) and 2) are not part of the lecture, you might have to prove them too. That shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Hello mate, and thank you so much for your help. With your response in mind, I think I have answered the question. For proper formatting I have added it as an answer to this question below, and I would appreciate it if you could give it the once over and hilight any flaws or additions you would suggest. Also, what do you think to my counterexample for part B? Thank you once again

Comment: Part A: Your proof seems fine to me. Part B: That is no counterexample. The intersection of those sets is the emptyset $\emptyset$. But $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb R^d$ are open and closed.

Comment: ok, I have updated it with possibly a better counter example. Thank you for your continued help.

Comment: I don't understand your new Part B. The sets $\left(\frac{n}2,1-\frac{n}2\right)$ are all open and an arbitrary union of open sets are open. That is exactly my point 2).

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is a limit point of $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\Omega_k$ then $x$ is a limit point of each $\Omega_k$ and therefore, since each $\Omega_k$ is closed, $x$ belongs to all of them. That is, $x\in\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\Omega_k$.

On the other hand, if you take *any* set $S$, you have $S=\bigcup_{x\in S}\{x\}$, and each $\{x\}$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

**Part A:**

Let $S$ $=$ $$\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\left(\mathbb \Omega_\alpha\right)$$

By applying the generalised de Morgan's Law we see that the complement $S^c$ is:

$S^c$ $=$ $$(\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\left(\mathbb \Omega_\alpha\right))^c$$ $=$ $$\bigcup_{\alpha\in I}\left(\mathbb \Omega_\alpha^c\right)$$

$ \forall \alpha \in I, \Omega_\alpha$ is closed, and so $\forall \alpha \in I, \Omega_\alpha^c$ is open.

The union of an arbitrary family of open sets is open, so $S^c$ is open.

Therefore, $(S^c)^c = S$ is closed

S is closed.

End proof.

**Part B:**

An example of a not-closed union of closed sets would be 
$$\bigcup_{n=2}^\infty\left( \frac{n}{2}, 1-\frac{n}{2}\right)$$ $=$ $(0,1)$